# Do the SetUp and TearDown methods need [RequiresSTA] if tests have it?

Tags: nunit, resharper, watin

I can run my WatiN tests with ReSharper without issues. Each test has the [RequiresSTA](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5) attribute and runs fine.

When I try run all the tests in the class (TestFixture) I get the following error:

```
One or more child tests had errors
Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
<testname>  ignored: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method: TestSetup
<testname>  ignored: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method: TestSetup
<testname>  ignored: Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method: TestSetup
```

The error doesn't indicate what I need to change to make it work.

If I then select all the tests that have been ignored in the Unit Test Sessions window, I can run them without problems.

What must I change to allow me to run all the tests in the TestFixture?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have met the same problem. I changed SetUp() and TearDown() methods to be public, then it worked.

Comment: This also seems to be an issue in ReSharper 9 that this same solution seems to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I've always set the apartment state in the App.config file of my solution and the NUnit GUI runner runs entire fixtures as expected.

App.config starts off like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA"/>
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>
  <appSettings>
........
```

Edit:  I'm using Watin2.1 and NUnit 2.5.