# Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#-4.0, tdd, nunit, installation

I am trying to do some dependency injection for my tests using nUnit. I'm new to TDD and nUnit so it's possible I am missing something simple. So basically I've created a SetUp method for my interfaces. I originally was using a constructor but I read it's bad to do this when doing TDD so I now using a method.

When I run my test I construct an object and assign it to the interface and then I call a method using that interface. I want to test if it can parse a string decimal.

When I run my test it says test failed and the message is:Invalid signature for SetUp or TearDown method

See below for the actual code:

```
 public class DonorTests
    {
        private IDonor _Donor;
        private IValidateInput _ValidInput;


        //DonorTests(IDonor donor, IValidateInput validInput)
        //{
        //    _Donor = donor;
        //    _ValidInput = validInput;
        //}

        [SetUp]
        void Setup(IDonor donor, IValidateInput validInput)
        {
            _Donor = donor;
            _ValidInput = validInput;
        }

        [Test]
        public void HandleStringNotDecimal()
        {
            _ValidInput = new ValidateInput();
            Assert.IsTrue(_ValidInput.IsDecimal("3445.3450"));
        }
    }
```

**My class that uses this interface**

```
 public class ValidateInput : IValidateInput
    {
        public decimal RoundTwoDecimalPlaces(decimal amount)
        {
            return Math.Round(amount);
        }

        public bool IsDecimal(string amount)
        {
            decimal ParsedDecimal;
            return Decimal.TryParse(amount, out ParsedDecimal);
        }

        public decimal ConvertToString(string value)
        {
            decimal ParsedDecimal;
            Decimal.TryParse(value, out ParsedDecimal);
            return ParsedDecimal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: setup needs to throw Exception.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're injecting dependencies using constructor injection previously, right? I think you will not be able to perform dependency injection using method decorated with `SetUpAttribute` because such method has to be parameterless. Also `Setup` method has to be `public`, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17778870/3242721).

How are we typically dealing with similar situations in our company is:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DonorTests
{
    private IDonor _Donor;
    private IValidateInput _ValidInput;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _Donor = new Donor();
        _ValidInput = new ValidateInput();
    }

    [Test]
    public void HandleStringNotDecimal()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(_ValidInput.IsDecimal("3445.3450"));
    }
}
```

Or if construction of `ValidInput` and `Donor` is cheap then we simply create new instance for each test, having special method for that purpose so when we decide to test another implementation of `IValidateInput` then it is enough to change it in one place only:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DonorTests
{
    [Test]
    public void HandleStringNotDecimal()
    {
        var validInput = CreateValidateInput();
        Assert.IsTrue(validInput .IsDecimal("3445.3450"));
    }

    private static IValidateInput CreateValidateInput()
    {
        return new ValidateInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Michal, your post and the link to the other SO thread helped me change the code so it passes the test.

Answer (score 18):

Besides the cause mentioned in the accepted answer, I have met the same error when leaving method as non-public (`private`  or `protected`).

NUnit most probably relies on reflection and does not deal with non-public methods, so special methods (i.e. decorated with NUnit specific attributes) must be `public`.

Comment: I believe thats exactly what I meant by saying "Also Setup method has to be public" in my answer :)

Comment: @MichalHosala - did not notice that, since the answer primarily deals with how to pass dependencies. I typically add this kind of info (important, but side info) at the end of the answer as a note in its own paragraph to be visible.